# Adding badge and styling columns on DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

**Problem**

I want to style the Datatable to look like this with status in a bootstrap "badge" class:[image],

With my code below, this is what I have this : [image]

I have data from mysql database loaded into Datatables via AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#transactionTable').DataTable( {
  "ajax": "walletTable.php",
  "bPaginate":true,
  "order":[[1,"desc"]],
  "bProcessing": true,
  "aoColumnDefs":[
    { "sClass": "badge badge-success", "aTargets":[4]}
  ],
  "columns": [
            {mData: 'id'},
            {mData: 'Date'},
            {mData: 'Amount', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',','.',0,' ')},
            {mData: 'Info'},
            {mData: 'Status'}
          ]
        });

    });
  </script>
```

The walletTable.php gets the data from database and sends it into a json array

***walletTable.php***

```
$tableSQL = "SELECT `id` as id, `amount` as Amount, `time` as Date, `status` as Status, `type` as Info FROM `transactionhistory` ORDER BY `transactionhistory`.`time` DESC";

 $getTable = mysqli_query($conn, $tableSQL);
$data = array();
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getTable) ) {
$data[] = $rows;
}
$results = array(
"sEcho" => 1,
"iTotalRecords" => count($data),
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
"aaData" => $data
);
echo json_encode($results);
```

and the HTML table

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="transactionTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                 <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Date</th>
                   <th>Amount</th>
                   <th>Info</th>
                   <th>Status</th>
                   </tr>
                 </thead>

                 </table>
             </div>
```

I'll also like to have a function like this to change the color of the badge with the status

```
function badgeColor($badgeStatus){
  if ($badgeStatus == "success") {
    echo "badge-success";
  }elseif ($badgeStatus == "pending") {
      echo "badge-info";
  }elseif ($badgeStatus == "failed") {
      echo "badge-danger";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm doing things a little differently, but maybe this can help you in some way.

I'm using PHP to load my data into a DataTable. After my connection to the server and query, I load the data into the variable *$stmt* and then do the following (I've removed the actual column names):

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //0
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //1
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //2
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //3
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //4
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //5
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //6
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //7
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //8
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //9
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //10
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //11
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //12
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //13
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //16

  if($row['ColumnName'] > 0){
    echo "<td> <span class=\"badge badge-pill badge-primary\">".$row['ColumnName']."%</span></td>"; //17
  }
  else{
    echo "<td> <span class=\"badge badge-pill badge-danger\">".$row['ColumnName']."%</span></td>"; //17
  }

  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //18
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //19
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //20
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //21
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //22
  echo "<td>".$row['ColumnName']."</td>"; //23
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

This isn't the most elegant solution, but I'm relatively new to web development and since this is my company's intranet facing site, they don't care about the code being elegant.

[Proof that it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6iZs.png)

Hopefully this is useful to you and I apologize if it's not a great answer... This is my first time answering a question on here lol.